# How to unbind element then allow that element to bind again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having some issues with using jQuery to unbind then bind an element dynamically.

I'm attempting to create a type of tabbing system that someone can use when browsing the site on mobile.  I want the user to be able to select the right arrow and have the `ul.tube` move `margin-left: -300px` (which is working fine). And the left arrow will make the `ul.tube` move `margin-left: 300px` (which also works fine).

The issue that I'm asking about happens when you hit the max `margin-left` of `-900px`, the code unbinds the right arrow.  I would like it when you start to click the left arrow again after reaching the `-900px`, to rebind the right arrow.  This will allow people to tab back to the right after having tabbed fully to the left.

[Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWymM.jpg)

Below is the HTML code example.

```
<div id="how-we_set">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left left"></i><br>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right right"></i><p></p>
    <ul class="tube">
        <li>Discovery</li>
        <li>Discovery 2</li>
        <li>Discovery 3</li>
        <li>Discovery 4</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1">
        <div><span>This is some text</span>This is some text</div>
        <div><span>This is some text</span>This is some text</div>
        <div><span>This is some text</span>This is some text</div>
        <div><span>This is some text</span>This is some text</div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
        <div><span>This is some text</span>This is some text</div>
        <div><span>This is some text</span>This is some text</div>
        <div><span>This is some text</span>This is some text</div>
        <div><span>This is some text</span>This is some text</div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3">
        <div><span>This is some text</span>This is some text</div>
        <div><span>This is some text</span>This is some text</div>
        <div><span>This is some text</span>This is some text</div>
        <div><span>This is some text</span>This is some text</div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab4">
        <div><span>This is some text</span>This is some text</div>
        <div><span>This is some text</span>This is some text</div>
        <div><span>This is some text</span>This is some text</div>
        <div><span>This is some text</span>This is some text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the Javascript I have so far.

```
// MOBILE DESIGN TAB
$('#how-we_set i.right').click(function handler() {
    $("#how-we_set ul.tube li").addClass("active");
    $("#how-we_set i.left").css('color', 'rgba(0,0,0,1.0)');
    $('#how-we_set ul.tube').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "-=300px"
    },
    function () {
      if ($(this).css ('marginLeft') >= "-900px") {
        $("#how-we_set i.right").unbind('click', handler);
        $("#how-we_set i.right").css('color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)');
      }
    });
});
$('#how-we_set i.left').click(function handler2() {
    $("#how-we_set i.right").css('color', 'rgba(0,0,0,1.0)');
    $('#how-we_set ul.tube').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "+=300px"
    },
    function () {
      if ($(this).css ('marginLeft') >= "0px") {
        $("#how-we_set i.left").unbind('click');
        $("#how-we_set i.left").css('color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)');
      }
    });
    $('#how-we_set i.right').bind(handler);
});
```

After looking at the example screenshot I'm sure you can understand that I'm attempting to tab the image and all content below each time an arrow is clicked.

How can I make this work as I expect?  Is there is a better way to approach this?  I'm open to new ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, with dedicated handler functions:

```
$('#how-we_set i.right').click(right_click_handler);
$('#how-we_set i.left').click(left_click_handler);

function bind_handlers(element) {
    if (parseInt(element.css('marginLeft')) <= -900) {
        $("#how-we_set i.right").css('color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)');
    } else {
        $("#how-we_set i.right").bind('click', right_click_handler);
    }

    if (parseInt(element.css('marginLeft') >= 0) {
        $("#how-we_set i.left").css('color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)');
    } else {
        $("#how-we_set i.left").bind('click', left_click_handler);
    }
};

function right_click_handler() {
    $("#how-we_set i.right").unbind('click', right_click_handler);
    $("#how-we_set ul.tube li").addClass("active");
    $("#how-we_set i.left").css('color', 'rgba(0,0,0,1.0)');
    $('#how-we_set ul.tube').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "-=300px"
    },
    function () {
        bind_handlers($(this));
    });
};

function left_click_handler() {
    $("#how-we_set i.left").unbind('click', left_click_handler);
    $("#how-we_set i.right").css('color', 'rgba(0,0,0,1.0)');
    $('#how-we_set ul.tube').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "+=300px"
    },
    function () {
        bind_handlers($(this));
    });
};
```

These changes only affect the handler registration.  Note that in the original jsFiddle, both buttons start off as enabled, but the top (left) button should be disabled.  If you click the top button first, it gets a little funny because of initial state; clicking the bottom button first works just fine and avoids the funny behavior.

You might consider some refactoring to reduce redundancy in the code.  I've refactored it like this (the jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mgaskill/w5kz7e1h/):

```
var how_we_set = $("#how-we_set");
var ul_tube = how_we_set.find("ul.tube");
var ul_tube_li = ul_tube.find("li");
var right_i = how_we_set.find("i.right");
var left_i = how_we_set.find("i.left");

function right_click_handler() {
    click_handler($(this), "-=300px");
};

function left_click_handler() {
    click_handler($(this), "+=300px");
};

function click_handler(element, amount) {
    right_i.unbind('click', right_click_handler);
    left_i.unbind('click', left_click_handler);

    ul_tube_li.addClass("active");
    ul_tube.animate({
        'marginLeft' : amount
    },
    update_buttons_state);
};

function update_buttons_state() {
    var marginLeft = parseInt(ul_tube.css('marginLeft'));

    right_i.css('color', 'rgba(0,0,0,1.0)');
    left_i.css('color', 'rgba(0,0,0,1.0)');

    if (+marginLeft <= -900) {
      right_i.css('color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)');
    } else {
      right_i.bind('click', right_click_handler);
    }

    if (marginLeft >= 0) {
      left_i.css('color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)');
    } else {
      left_i.bind('click', left_click_handler);
    }
};

update_buttons_state();
```

This is still about the same number of lines of code, but caches jQuery lookups and re-uses all of the click handling logic between the left and right buttons, so you'll have consistent behavior between the buttons.  And with a separate function to `update_buttons_state()`, you can call this before the UI runs the first time to make sure that the button states don't allow strange behavior due to improper initial state.

The updated code also unbinds the click handlers prior to the `animate` call, to prevent applying multiple quick clicks while the animation is running.  Additionally, the comparison to the right-hand limit (`-900px`) is done by converting the pixel count to an integer, to allow the proper comparison.

Comment: Hello Michael,
Thank you for the reply. This is getting closer to what I'm looking for, but just notice when I click the next arrow when using your code after the first click it goes from adding nagitive margins to adding positive margins. As seem in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/npd5kst7/). Any additional advise would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am presently adding more advice.  I'll test in the fiddle and let you know when I believe it's doing what you want.

Comment: @Cehrlichman I updated and tested the initial code, and then I refactored and tested that code, as well.  There's an initial state bug in the original jsFiddle that I fixed in the refactored code.  The answer contains the details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your continued help with this! I think we're getting real close. I added the code you suggested and got the following result which I've recorded in a [video](https://youtu.be/M2Um925L4vw). When you initially tab to the right, it disables the button and enables the left arrow (which is good), but we don't wan't to disable the right button until you get to -900px. You will notice in the video that if you click on each arrow quickly that you can bypass the unbind effect. In the video when you see it scrolling to the far right, its due to multiple clicks.

Comment: @Cehrlichman I have fixed both issues and provided a link to an updated (working) jsFiddle in the answer.  The refactored version of the code is used in the jsFiddle and actually works better than the non-refactored code.  Let me know if you have any other issues, but I believe that it's working as expected now.

Comment: Thank you again for all your help. I have another [video] (https://youtu.be/gb4GKHhH6yc) recorded to help illustrate what its doing now. Looks like we're close.

Comment: @Cehrlichman if you check the line `if (marginLeft >= 0)` in your code, it should have `0`, not `"0px"`, and that should make it work as expected.  It's already included in the answer, and when I revert the change back in [the jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mgaskill/w5kz7e1h/) to `"0px"`, I get the behavior that you showed in your video.

Comment: The code used within the video had only `0` not `"0px"`. Could it be anything else? Again, I appreciate your help with this and would be happy to compensate for your time.

Comment: @Cehrlichman The only other things that I can think of that can be happening is that a) the `unbind` isn't happening before the `animate` call in the `click_handler` function, or b) the `.click` methods are still included at the end, just before the call to `update_buttons_state()` at the end.  If neither of those fix it, I'd actually have to look at your real code to see what's happening.  No compensation necessary, but an upvote when you accept the answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: I will of course be giving you an upvote. I attempted both methods and am still running into the same issue. Here is a pastbin with my current script http://pastebin.com/Bd2f1mCX

Comment: @Cehrlichman Aha! Line 33 in your pastebin shows that the `update_buttons_state` function gets called at the end of the first `animate`, and before the second `animate`.  What happens is that this installs the click handlers, which allows clicking during the second animation.  Try changing the `update_buttons_state` in line 33 to `function() {}` and see what happens.  I'm going to send you my contact info through your website in just a bit, in case this doesn't work, or you run into any more difficulties.

Comment: That worked great! Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: @Cehrlichman My pleasure, and glad to help.  It was an enjoyable little project.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
$('#how-we_set i.right').click(function handler() {
```

with

```
$('#how-we_set).on('click', 'i.right', function() {})
```

Same way for the another handler.
Here's very brief [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jo5sbLo1/).

Read about event delegation in jQuery [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Hello Vladimir,
Thank you for your reply.
That seemed to solve that issue but now brings up another issue.
The code that unbinds the button no longer works 
`$('#how-we_set ul.tube').animate({
   'marginLeft' : "-=300px"
  },
  function () {
    if ($(this).css ('marginLeft') >= "-900px") {
   $("#how-we_set i.right").unbind('click', handler);
   $("#how-we_set i.right").css('color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)');
    }
  });`
My goal is that once someone clicks the right button and the UL scrolls to -900px, i want the button to be disabled (because there will be no more content to look at).

Comment: try to ask your question in another post. Its not a good way to ask the solution of a following issue in the former question.

Comment: @xetra11 - I should have clarified my comment, my apologies. Basically, I want the button to stop working (or unbind) once `#how-we_set ul.tube` gets to `margin-left: -900px`. When I use @vladimir-tagay code, my function that checks for the `margin-left: -900px` stops working.